# What does ! mean at the end of a Ruby method definition?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby by reading code, but I bumped into the following situation, which I cannot find in any of my tutorials/cheatsheets.

```
def foo!
    # do bar

    return bar  
  end
```

What is the point of "!" in a method definition?

Comment: What does `//` mean at the beginning of a Ruby method definition body?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby doesn't treat the `!` as a special character at the end of a method name.  By convention, methods ending in `!` have some sort of side-effect or other issue that the method author is trying to draw attention to.  Examples are methods that do in-place changes, or might throw an exception, or proceed with an action despite warnings.

For example, here's how `String#upcase!` compares to `String#upcase`:

```
1.9.3p392 :004 > foo = "whatever"
 => "whatever"
1.9.3p392 :005 > foo.upcase
 => "WHATEVER"
1.9.3p392 :006 > foo
 => "whatever"
1.9.3p392 :007 > foo.upcase!
 => "WHATEVER"
1.9.3p392 :008 > foo
 => "WHATEVER"
```

ActiveRecord makes extensive use of bang-methods for things like `save!`, which raises an exception on failure (vs `save`, which returns true/false but doesn't raise an exception).

It's a "heads up!" flag, but there's nothing that enforces this.  You could end all your methods in `!`, if you wanted to confuse and/or scare people.

Comment: May want to add a note that `!` methods tend to have different return values (most notably `nil` when nothing changed) which can cause unexpected and subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a "bang" method, which changes the receiver and is a convention in Ruby.

You can define a `!` version which might work like a non-bang method, but then it would then mislead other programmers if they didn't look at your method definition.

bang method in turn returns `nil` when no changes made to the receiver.

Examples without `!` - You can see that the source string has not been changed:

```
str = "hello"
p str.delete("l") #=> "heo"
p str #=> "hello"
```

Examples with `!` - You can see that the source string has been changed:

```
str = "hello"
p str.delete!("l") #=> "heo"
p str #=> "heo"
```

NOTE: There are some non-bang version methods, which also can change the receiver object:

```
str = "hello"
p str.concat(" world") #=> "hello world"
p str #=> "hello world"
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, so it is just a ruby convention :D

Comment: The bang isn't used by itself. It's used when there is an non-bang alternative. http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist

Comment: @thomthom I know that, did I mention anything wrong there? point me to there,I will correct.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The `!` indicates that the method is a potentially dangerous version of another method. Many times, `!` does modify the receiver (and that is what is dangerous), but other times other effects occur. For example, in Rails, the ActiveRecord `save` and `save!` both modify the receiver (in a sense) but the `save!` method potentially raises and exception. Jim Stewart's answer is the correct answer.

Comment: @LeviStanley I don't know in what sense you told my answer is misleading. but wanted to tell you bang method returns `nil` if changes are not possible.This question is tagged as `Ruby`. So according to ruby what I wrote bang method does exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is not a method definition but is an convention used when you declaring an method and this method will **change** the object.

```
1.9.3-p194 :004 > a="hello "
 => "hello " 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > a.strip
 => "hello" 
1.9.3-p194 :006 > a
 => "hello " 
1.9.3-p194 :007 > a.strip!
 => "hello" 
1.9.3-p194 :008 > a
 => "hello"
```